# WPF groupbox is not displaying

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application with a XAML of one Grid
What I need to do is break it apart a bit for a better look and feel UI/UX

So the GroupBox seems like a nice way to create some nice separations.

(Typically I recall doing something similar with winforms years ago and I prefer to group controls first because rather than after a bunch of controls are added)

In my XAML I tried adding a GroupBox around a Label and I don't see either the Groupbox , and now the Label is not displaying as well, what am I doing wrong?

```
<GroupBox Header="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="404,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="400">
        <Label Style="{StaticResource EmbeddedLabel}" Content="Selected Trouble Call" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8"/>
    </GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include your Style in your example, but you should be able to go back to basics and add it in after and determine if that is the cause.  The margin you specified is suspect, and you might consider using something smaller and aligning overall using Grid/columns.  Try not setting the width/height on the GroupBox (at least for starters).  What you has is too small for a default Label.

Below is a working example of a GroupBox and Label.  It should work for you too.  Add your new stuff incrementally, and see when it breaks.

[image: Groupbox]